# Unexpected Byref/val behavior with List(Of) vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, list, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a custom control that has a panel where other controls display.  Whenever a control is displayed, I add it to a List(Of Control) called UCList.  Then, when they hit the Start Over button, I have a recursive function that clears each control, and any children, in the UCList.

Do lists deal with ref/val differently?  When I call my ResetUC function, a breakpoint at the call shows that "oCon is oCashCash" however, as soon as I get into the Reset Function with variable passed Byref, the above is false.  It still is the same type, has the same name, and children(with same values), etc.  But it is a new entity.  Simply changing it to accept a Byval instead of Byref, and everything is working ("oCon is oCashCash" even after passing into the reset function).

This behavior seems backwards to me.  Is my understanding wrong, or do lists deal with reference differently for some reason?  This is the first time I have been confused with how ref/val responds in quite a long time.

Edit:
control-level variable

```
Public UCList As List(Of Control)
```

Where control is added to list (most omitted)

```
ElseIf ControlName = "ConfirmCashCash" Then
        If Not UCList.Contains(oCashCash) Then
            UCList.Add(oCashCash)
        End If  
        pnlMain.Controls.Add(oCashCash)
```

Startover sub click event (originally was foreach, but I was trying to figure it out).  At this point, oCon is oCashCash
--Edited to show full button per request in comment--

```
Private Sub btnStartOver_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStartOver.MouseUp
    If pnlMain.Controls(0) Is oConfirmFinalize AndAlso oConfirmFinalize.btnFinalize.Text = "Finalize" Then
        If MessageBox.Show("Deal Is Not Finalized.  Are You Sure You Want To Leave This Page?", "Finalize Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
            Return
        End If
    End If
    If Not btnBack.Enabled Then
        If MessageBox.Show("Deal Is Editing And Not Finalized.  Are You Sure You Want To Leave This Page?", "Loss of Work Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
            Return
        End If
    End If
    ImpersonateUserID = String.Empty
    'For Each con As Control In UCList
    For i As Integer = 0 To UCList.Count - 1
        Dim oCon As Control = UCList(i)
        ResetUC(oCon)
    Next
    'ResetUC(New Control)
    'Next
    oConfirmFinalize.oLastCon = Nothing
    oConfirmFinalize.oConfirm = New Confirm()
    UCList.Clear()
    'ResetUC(pnlMain.Controls(0))
    ChangeUC("ConfirmMain", True, Nothing)
    btnBack.Enabled = True
    btnDelete.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Reset sub - byref it is NOT oCashCash; however, byval, it IS. (most omitted)

```
Private Sub ResetUC(ByVal oCon As Control)
    For Each con As Control In oCon.Controls
        If TypeOf con Is ConfirmIndexDetail Then
            DirectCast(con, ConfirmIndexDetail).DateNavigator1.DateTime = DateTime.Now()
        End If
        If con.HasChildren Then
            For Each child As Control In con.Controls
                ResetUC(child)
            Next
        End If
        'Code that clears fields.
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll update the op with snippets.

Comment: Is this winforms, asp, wpf? When it comes to objects, `byVal` passes copy of the pointer, so you can't change the object - only its properties. `ByRef` allows you to replace an object. But other consumers of the original object keep pointing to that object. this is what happens for you. question only - where?

Comment: I want to see everything your button `start over` does

Comment: Sorry it took so long.  Edited with full start over - not that I think anything else will help, and thus why I omitted it lol... But it's there now.  Also added winforms tag per your comment.  Thx for the advice.

Comment: I can't pinpoint the issue but what I said initially holds true. I see you do `UCList.Clear()` but just because you clear list, your controls are not gone. They're still there. You just out of sync somewhere. You hold reference to old list or something of that sort. If your controls are on some container already, why would you need a list? Try to lay out your logic so you don't have to use the list of controls, which are already part of control collection. Use list of strings (names of controls) as indexing device, and find them on form/control, or dictionary (if needed).